# Updating ubuntu server apt-get gives me - 404 Not Found

Tags: 11.04, apt, updates

I'm trying to update a Ubuntu server and when I run apt-get update I get a number of errors like the examples below (note I added some space after http).

```
Err http  ://no.archive.ubuntu.com natty/main Sources  404  Not Found
Err http  ://no.archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources 404  Not Found
```

AND

```
W: Failed to fetch http  ://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http  ://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/restricted/source/Sources  404  Not Found

I tried to replace all occurrences of http   ://no.archive.ubuntu.com/ with http  ://archive.ubuntu.com/
```

But seems all of these archives are gone...

Version of Ubuntu:
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
Release:        11.04
Codename:       natty

How can I cleanup this mess?
Thanx for any help!
j

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion, but there is no etc/apt/apt.conf file.
In /etc/apt I have the following:
apt.conf.d  preferences.d  secring.gpg  sources.list  sources.list~  sources.list.d  sources.list.distUpgrade  trustdb.gpg  trusted.gpg  trusted.gpg~  trusted.gpg.d

Comment: And in /etc/apt/apt.conf.d I have these files:
00CDMountPoint  00trustcdrom  01autoremove  05aptitude  20changelog  70debconf

Comment: Forgot to say that the example URLs don't seem to exist (tested on different machines on different networks), so I doubt it can be an issue with proxy as suggested in the link.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I assume the problem is because you are using a relatively old release of Ubuntu. A possible fix would be to open the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file with an editor of your choice
.Change all `(xx.)archive.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com.`. In your case an example would be `://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources` becomes

```
://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/natty/main/source/Sources
```

after this, you can try running `sudo apt-get update`

For you to update your release,you need `update-manager-core(sudo apt-get install update-manager-core)` and then `sudo do-release-upgrade` but this will update you to the next release and has to be repeated until you reach say 12.04 LTS which has Long Term Support.

Comment: Thank you! This solved the problem!
I also had to change to old-releases for security.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu 11.04 was supported for 18 months, and that means it's been unsupported for almost a year. If you have to use it, then you need to switch to old-releases archives, but please keep in mind that you will not get any security upgrades for it and there are known issues.

The correct way to "cleanup this mess" is to upgrade to a current version of Ubuntu. If you don't want to upgrade very often, the best suggestion is to get 12.04.3LTS, which will be supported until April 2017. You can upgrade LTS-releases directly from one to the next. You can't skip versions, so upgrading 11.04 would take a long time.

Comment: Thanx, yes this is what I'm about to endeavour on - get to 12.04

Comment: Then you can either upgrade to 11.10 via old-releases, then switch back to supported repos and upgrade to 12.04... Or perform a clean install. I think I'd recommend the latter. :)

Comment: I also had to remove the `us.` part.